# Value of this in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

I recently stumbled upon how `this` is defined at runtime in event listeners. As I understood so far, this is defined very dynamic at runtime. This means that the value of this points to the object a method is called upon:

```
object.doSomething() // this in doSomething points to object
```

Arrow functions on the other hand act differently. They don't have a `this` value, so `this` is taken from the execution context in which the arrow function is declared. This is why the instantly invoced arrow function logs the object even if it is not called on it:

```
const object = {
  name: 'foo',
  doSomething: doSomething,
};

function doSomething() {
  (function () {
    console.log(this); // Window
  })();
  (() => {
    console.log(this); // object foo
  })();
}

object.doSomething();
```

So far so good. Things seem to work differently in `addEventListener`:

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(this); // someElement
});

someElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  console.log(this); // window
});
```

Since `addEventListener` is called on `someElement` I would expect `this` inside `addEventListener` to point to that object. The regular callback function however is called as soon as the event occurs. It is not called on the object and should therefor point the `window`. But actually it points on `someElement`.

In the second example we see, that the arrowfunction logs `window`. Since I expect `this` inside `addEventListener` to point to `someElement`, this inside the arrow function should also point to `someElement`.

Long story short. `this` inside `addEventListener` behaves contrary to what I expected. Why is this?

Comment: The Web API [specifies](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) that the target of the callback be the element the event was raised on. When supplied with an arrow function, however, the target (ie. `this`) of the function cannot be set as the ECMAScript specification demands that it is automatically set *lexically*. Hence your observation.

Comment: This is not about the `addEventListener` itself, but it is about its callback function.

Comment: Actually I know what arrow functions are. So the linked questions do not answer my question. @BenAston thank you! This answers my question